# How Does a Windows Program Load a Kernel Driver Without Rebooting or Calling CreateService

Tags: windows, registry, device-driver, process-explorer, apimonitor

I know Sysinternals' Process Explorer silently loads a Device Driver called `PROCEXPxxx.SYS`. I'm wondering how it does this. To me, it looks like a good example of silently bundling a kernel mode component in our application.

First off, the driver is created dynamically from the exe (perhaps as a resource).

By using Process Monitor to check the registry, I can tell PE is using `RegCreateKey` to create the keys under `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\PROCEXPxxx` manually (and immediately delete it afterward so that nothing is left behind after the driver is running).

By using "`dumpbin /imports procexp.exe`", I found that PE doesn't import `CreateService` at all. And by using the API Monitor (http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), I did confirm that `CreateService` won't be called when we run it.

So, how does Process Explorer elegantly load a driver silently without rebooting and calling `CreateService`?

Comment: The solution might not, in fact, be elegant.  Note that kernel32.dll functions generally simply forward to ntdll.dll, and even ntdll.dll functions can be inlined into application code, the magic happens in the kernel, the application need only perform a `SYSENTER` instruction.

Comment: Also a possibility, that it uses the device driver installation functions (SetupDi*) and not the service manager functions.

Comment: Ben Voigt, SetupDi* are not involved as dumpbin shows it doesn't even import the setupapi.dll

Comment: It could load setupapi.dll dynamically.  But if all you really need is a solution for your own application, what's wrong with CreateService, followed by StartService?

Comment: Just curiosity, are there other possibilities apart from CreateService? The special thing about PE is that it deletes the registry key immediately while its driver is loaded and running? And somehow it deletes the .sys driver file from system32\drivers, too. Can we remove the driver directly by deleting the registry key without calling StopService/DeleteService? I suppose CreateService/DeleteService should be paired

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it looks to me that it is calling `NtLoadDriver()` to load the driver.